# How to make SKSpriteNode follow another SKSpriteNode with Sprite Kit in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two SKSpriteNodes:

```
SKSpriteNode *leader = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(20,20)];

SKSpriteNode *follower = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(20,20)];
```

I was wondering what the best way would to go about making the follower "follow" the actions of the leader node.

For example, if I were to call:

```
SKAction *first = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0, 100) duration:1.0];
SKAction *second = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(100,0) duration:1.0];
[leader runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[first, second]]];
```

How could I have the follower node follow the leader node during its actions?
What if I had 10 follower nodes, how could I make each node follow the one in front of it (like a line)?

Comment: Make them a child of the leading node.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an action for all 10 nodes for them to follow the node in front.

node2 should MoveTo node1.position

Place this method inside the update function.

I recommend you assign the action with a key.
And at every update remove the actions with that key before you assign the new moveTo actions.

Here's some code:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
[node1 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node2 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node3 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node4 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node5 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node6 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node7 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node8 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node9 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node10 removeActionForKey:@"Move"];
[node1 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(leaderNode.position.x - (node1.frame.width / 2), leaderNode.position.y - (node1.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node2 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node1.position.x - (node2.frame.width / 2), node1.position.y - (node2.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node3 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node2.position.x - (node3.frame.width / 2), node2.position.y - (node3.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node4 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node3.position.x - (node4.frame.width / 2), node3.position.y - (node4.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node5 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node4.position.x - (node5.frame.width / 2), node4.position.y - (node5.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node6 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node5.position.x - (node6.frame.width / 2), node5.position.y - (node6.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node7 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node6.position.x - (node7.frame.width / 2), node6.position.y - (node7.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node8 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node7.position.x - (node8.frame.width / 2), node7.position.y - (node8.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node9 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node8.position.x - (node9.frame.width / 2), node8.position.y - (node9.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
[node10 runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(node9.position.x - (node10.frame.width / 2), node9.position.y - (node10.frame.height / 2)) duration:1] withKey:"Move"]
}
```

This should work as long you already made the variables.

The nodes will line up diagonally to the leaderNode. Change CGPointMake to adjust where it lines up.

If you want, you could put this method somewhere else. Possibly place it in the same place as where you move the leaderNode.

So if the leaderNode gets moved in touchesMoved, maybe place it there.

BTW, you could make this into a loop if you want to make it compact.

Comment: If you stuck all the follower nodes into an array, you could just cycle through the array assigning the SKAction to each node. This results in substantially less code than what you have above.

Comment: If you fully read my answer, I said "BTW, you could make this into a loop if you want to make it compact."

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case, you could make all followers be added as a child of leader, and position relative to the leader..

`[leader addchild:follower]` (x10).

Any movement of the leader is automatically applied to the children.

Comment: How do I prevent them from stacking on top of the leader so I can put them in a line?

Comment: @Lasonic change their positions